What are some things the church fathers agreed on unanimously that modern Christians disagree with them on?
For example:

it seems the church fathers unanimously were in agreement that owning slaves isn't a sin per se except for a few such as Gregory of Nyssa, but modern Christians though, strongly oppose this view.

Church fathers were unanimous on contraception being wrong, but many Christians disagree with this.

Church fathers seemed to unanimously believe Women were in many ways inferior to Men.


What are some other things most modern Christians disagree with the church fathers on, i e. opinions they held pretty unanimously?

It is very easy to say who the Church Fathers were. It is not so easy to say who 'modern Christians' are. This site recognises that fact and it requires the questioner to define, within the question, whose view they wish to hear about. The self-identifying term 'Christian' (modern or otherwise) covers a vast spectrum of opinion.

Welcome to SE-C. Please see the Tour and the Help (below) as to the purpose and the functioning of the site. Please also see the archive of 15,000 question/answer contributions as to how these policies play out in practice. Moderators are elected by the Community of users to maintain the integrity of the site.

The question as is is far too broad to elicit a good answer.

I believe it is easy to say who "modern" christians are. In a broad sense because I believe my own church is the original one that all others split off of. Note "holiness defined" that this is the perspective of many people. Except for those modern groups who hold that they are reforming the church (LDS for example).

First I'll respond to the things mentioned in the question. As usual my denominational perspective might bias my answer. I am eastern Orthodox.
There will be a compressed short answer at the bottom.

Slavery: In simple terms slavery in ancient times was very common, and actually not as bad as what people think of today. There are different types of slavery, and from the context of Jewish law slavery was very "mild" compared to those of the other nations around them. (You technically had to treat slaves decently, you had to free them every 7 years on a fixed time system (instead of forever), you had to provide them with the ability to start a new life...) Unlike what happened in modern history a few hundred years ago or modern slavery in some asian countries or human trafficking...
Contraception: I can only answer from the Orthodox perspective here, obviously they condemn sex outside of marriage. Within marriage however, the use of non-abortive methods is accepted by the american orthodox church. However some orthodox churches still remain firmly in the NFP and abstinence position. This is different from catholics because the Orthodox Church recognizes that sex is an expression of love between a married couple, it does not need to cause procreation. Similar to how food is for nourishment, but it is not sinful to enjoy some chocolate.
Woman: Uh... As far as I know due to the Theotokos women are highly respected. The first Christian was female, the best non-God example we have is a Woman. Women have a different role within life, within the church, etc. It is not lesser, it is different. There are many female saints... uh, women found the tomb of Christ (and were apostles to the apostles) so... yeah no.
The most important, most honored, most remembered non-God human to have ever lived was Mary/Theotokos. The one who stands as the entry point for God into the world. The queen of heaven. The one whom all generations will call blessed.
But women (and men) are still expected to be respectful, elegant, and appropriate. I would suggest that modern western churches that allow female clergy are new.

After the recent edit, I think I can add some additional things, of theological significance.
There is the concept of unity among christians with regards to doctrine and belief. I do not believe I need to provide a list of each denomination that has "variation" from another faith, as it is obvious. The ancient church fathers must be scandalized watching us as they pray for us. Considering how they felt about heresy.
The protestant churches tend to undervalue the extra writings of Church fathers. For example if the earliest christians univocally said that X or Y is true... the orthodox church trust that it is true. This is simply because from our understanding and belief we don't believe that the Holy Spirit would allow the entire Church to fall into heresy. (This feels like a meta answer, considering the question) But I believe the ancient church fathers would reference each other occasionally and there was no doubt in their minds about the credibility involved.
Another common one I can think of is the protestant view that the Eucharist is "just a symbolic" thing. Where as the ancient church fathers believe in the real presence of Christ in the Eucharist.

St. Ignatius to the Smyrnaeans on the subject of the Gnostics: They abstain from the Eucharist and from prayer, because they confess not the Eucharist to be the flesh of our Saviour Jesus Christ, which suffered for our sins, and which the Father, of His goodness, raised up again. Those, therefore, who speak against this gift of God, incur death in the midst of their disputes. But it were better for them to treat it with respect, that they also might rise again. It is fitting, therefore, that you should keep aloof from such persons, and not to speak of them either in private or in public, but to give heed to the prophets, and above all, to the Gospel, in which the passion [of Christ] has been revealed to us, and the resurrection has been fully proved. But avoid all divisions, as the beginning of evils.

Please compare with such statements like these.

Gateway Baptist: The Lord's Supper is a symbolic act of obedience whereby members of the church, through partaking of the bread and the fruit of the vine, memorialize the death of the Redeemer and anticipate His second coming.

St John's Baptist Church has a little bit of detail on this as well.


United Methodist Church: Believe Christ is present when taking communion but does not believe in transubstantiation
Presbyterians: Bread is a loaf of bread to represent the fullness of God's love.



Short version of the answer, anything after number 6 are without references and purely from memory...

Slavery, this is a misconception. It is not the same as slavery in recent history.
Contraception, within marriage there is nothing sinful with using non-murderous methods to control family growth. Eros is part of love. (Orthodox perspective)
Women, are actually highly valued and respected. Their roles are different! But not considered lesser.
Unity, I think everyone actually agrees we should have 1 church, but ultimately the acceptance of multiple churches is already scandalous.
Value of previous church fathers, they clearly trusted each other, we do modern churches doubt them?
The Real presence of Christ in the Eucharist, it was not considered symbolic (except by heretics)
That the scriptures are the pillar and support of the truth (Solo/a Scriptura) instead of the Church.
Sola Fide is new... Church fathers have high value on "bearing fruit" and such.
Some modern churches are "free floating" without a bishop, that would be unthinkable in ancient times.
Apostolic succession, church fathers highly valued this, many protestants do not care.


"Slavery" in Scripture wasn't that far from owing money. Got a home, car or school loan? You might be a "slave" in the view of the ancients.  Also, I think you forgot that Earth was almost unanimously believed to be a few thousand years old.

@Matthew I could have gone into detail about how spiritual revelation on a personal level was considered important, compared to now where intellectual rational thought prevails. I could have also gone into some detail about how they are intellectually critical of the jewish religious leaders (and how today we really are more sympathetic). I could point out that in the early church the Eucharist was not "symbolic" it was considered to be literal. I mean... without some framework on the original question I will not elaborate on the multitude of other issues or your pet project subject.
